# JetBrains reset. Сброс настроек для триал-версии до 30 дней

Tags: ide, jetbrains

Каким образом сбросить настройки на продукты JetBrains до триальной версии?

**Дисклаймер**

*Отмечу, что данный вопрос и ответ к нему созданы исключительно в образовательных целях и не несут никакого призыва к действию.*

*Любое платное ПО должно покупаться*

*[Обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11319/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-so-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) на мете о целесобразности вопроса*

Comment: Странно почему минусуют, будто никто никогда не делал так :\

Comment: Оно опять в очереди "Сообщения низкого качества", когда пост на мете смотрел вопрос на скриншоте как-то побогаче выглядел...ну и метка `crack` это, имхо, перебор немного. Если раньше с какими-то оговорками можно было сказать, что это все ради науки, то данная метка оставленная автором как бы намекает что именно ему нужно.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Окей. Убрал. На мете то же самое https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11319/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-so-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81

Comment: сорри, значит показалось.

Comment: Я бы советовал дисклеймер поставить не в ответе а в вопросе. И желательно избыточный, с дополнениями о том, что так не стоит делать, что ПО нужно покупать, и что это немного может по закону преследоваться. Вопрос и так достаточно спорный. В текущем своем состоянии он из очереди низкого качества не выберется. Где вы еще минусов огребете(не все мету читают) и его опять закроют. А если тревог еще словит, то и удалят еще рвз. После чего не факт, что Квертий Вам еще раз поможет. Дисклеймер хоть чуть поубавит пыл проверяющих. И так он сможет из очереди низкого качества выбраться

Comment: Думаю сюда ещё не раз попадут люди пытающиеся сбросить пробный период программ от JetBrain что бы продолжать пользоваться бесплатно. Наверное будет уместно упомянуть что есть возможность поучаствовать в программе предварительного тестирования и нечего не сбрасывать. https://www.jetbrains.com/resources/eap/

Comment: на маке можно запустить в терминале `sudo fs_usage -w`, запустить продукт и попытаться отследить в консольных дебрях места требующие чистки (рекомендуется закрыть все остальное, чтобы снизить шум); также замечено, что продукт любит писать в расширенные атрибуты файлов проектов, чистить через `/usr/bin/xattr -cr </path/to/projects>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Легко заметить, путём перебора файлов, которые относятся к JetBrains, что валидация триальной версии завязана на несколько файлов:

- `~/.config/JetBrains/GoLand2020.2/eval`
- `~/.config/JetBrains/GoLand2020.2/options/usage.statistics.xml`
- `~/.config/JetBrains/GoLand2020.2/options/other.xml`
- `~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/recentProjects.xml`
- `~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/updates.xml`
- `~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/usage.statistics.xml`
- `~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains`
- `~/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml`
- `~/.java/.userPrefs/.user.lock.user`
- `~/.java/.userPrefs/.userRootModFile.user`

Тогда можно смастерить такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://gist.github.com/Hedgehogues/123eb27100608d248cf8370e666b29ce/

# declare array of tools
declare -a tools=(
    "DataGrip"
    "CLion"
    "Rider"
    "WebStorm"
    "GoLand"
    "PyCharm"
)

for tool in "${tools[@]}"
do
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/eval
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/usage.statistics.xml
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/other.xml
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/recentProjects.xml
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/updates.xml
    rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/$tool*/options/usage.statistics.xml
    rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains
    rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml        
    rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/.user.lock.user
    rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/.userRootModFile.user
done
```

После чего, добавить его в `PATH`. Для того, чтобы каждый раз при загрузке он был доступен из консоли, можно добавить следующую строку в `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/script
```

Чтобы не перезагружаться, сделать следует так:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Данный ответ опубликован в информационных целях

Comment: С версии 2021.3 требует залогиниться в аккаунте, чтобы получить триал. Насколько одноразовая 30-дневка пока не проверяла.

Answer (score 12):

В продуктах Jetbrains 2021 года вышеприведённые советы не работают, рабочее решение такое:
Settings -- Plugins -- Manage plugin repositories -- Add -- https://plugins.zhile.io -- OK -- Search 'ide eval reset' -- Install -- Help -- Eval Reset

Comment: И этот перестанет работать:) Хотя похоже разработчики этой "IDE" не читают этот сайт.

Comment: Нет, они просто откладывают исправление этих способов что бы вы могли ими пока-что пользовакться, т.к. те кому оно реально надо, продукт купят, те кому нет, перейдёт на бесплатные аналоги. А вот если продукт станет качественным, а ты за время нескольких тестовых периодов на него нормально подсядешь, то перейти на аналоги тебе будет куда сложнее.

Comment: Уже не работает и этот вариант. Теперь используется javaagent `ja netfilter` + сервер активации/ключ.

Comment: its try! Thanks